# Error al cambiar color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hace poco estaba en mi curso de JavaScript y me mandaron a hacer un ejercicio en cuestion, como este:

> Crea una página que muestre cinco cuadrados pequeños de diferentes
> colores y un cuadrado grande.  Cuando el ratón pase por encima de
> alguno de ellos, el color de fondo del cuadrado grande será del color
> de relleno del cuadrado pequeño.

El problema está en que según yo he escrito bien el codigo pero no funciona, dejo mi codigo a continuación:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#rojo { background-color: red; }
#azul { background-color: blue; }
#amarillo { background-color: yellow; }
#verde { background-color: green; }
#marron { background-color: brown; }

#CajaCambiante {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ejercicio 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script>
    function cambio(e) {
      bg = e.style.backgroundColor;
      document.getElementById('CajaCambiante').style.backgroundColor = bg;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="rojo" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="azul" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="amarillo" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="verde" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="marron" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="CajaCambiante"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

¿Alguien puede decirme donde he fallado?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar una imagen de pantalla del error o comportamiento inadecuado?

Comment: simplemente no cambia de color, no hace nada, y no me marca ni error ni nada

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error o problema? Decir *no funciona* no es de mucha ayuda. Por favor leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: fallaste por que no funciona

Comment: que ha hecho para verificar que error puede tener??

Answer (score 11):

La función se ejecuta correctamente, pero hay un problema aquí:

```
bg = e.style.backgroundColor;
```

El problema es que `e.style.backgroundColor` va a funcionar sólo si tienes los estilos *inline*, pero viendo tu código, ese no es el caso. Pon los estilos en la propia etiqueta o usa data-atributos para solucionar eso.

Ésta sería una manera de solucionar el problema corrigiendo el punto de arriba (poniendo los estilos directamente en la etiqueta):

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#rojo { background-color: red; }
#azul { background-color: blue; }
#amarillo { background-color: yellow; }
#verde { background-color: green; }
#marron { background-color: brown; }

#CajaCambiante {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ejercicio 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script>
    function cambio(e) {
      const bg = e.style.backgroundColor;
      document.getElementById('CajaCambiante').style.backgroundColor = bg;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="rojo" onmouseover="cambio(this)" style="background-color: red"></div>
  <div id="azul" onmouseover="cambio(this)" style="background-color: blue"></div>
  <div id="amarillo" onmouseover="cambio(this)" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
  <div id="verde" onmouseover="cambio(this)" style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div id="marron" onmouseover="cambio(this)" style="background-color: brown"></div>
  <div id="CajaCambiante"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Probablemente los data-atributos son una mejor opción y mantendría el código más limpio. En lugar de poner `style="background-color: red;` harías `data-color="red"`. Y en JavaScript lo leerías así: `e.dataset.color`.

Comment: Buenísima respuesta!

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Perfecto, aunque no es mi ejercicio, aprendí al copiarlo a code pen y analizarlo.

Answer (score 7):

Probablemente, la opción más fácil sería usar clases en lugar de ID y solo necesitas asignar al contenedor la clase del elemento que disparó el evento:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rojo { background-color: red; }
.azul { background-color: blue; }
.amarillo { background-color: yellow; }
.verde { background-color: green; }
.marron { background-color: brown; }

#CajaCambiante {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ejercicio 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script>
    function cambio(element) {
      document.getElementById('CajaCambiante').className = element.className;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rojo" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div class="azul" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div class="amarillo" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div class="verde" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div class="marron" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="CajaCambiante"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Otra manera de hacerlo es a través de la función `getComputedStyle()` del objeto `window`. Esta función si que nos devuelve los estilos que estén afectando al elemento, aunque estos no se encuentren en línea.

```css
.cuadrado {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#rojo { background-color: red; }
#azul { background-color: blue; }
#amarillo { background-color: yellow; }
#verde { background-color: green; }
#marron { background-color: brown; }

#CajaCambiante {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ejercicio 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script>
    function cambio(e) {
      let bg = window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
      document.getElementById('CajaCambiante').style.backgroundColor = bg;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="rojo" class="cuadrado" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="azul" class="cuadrado" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="amarillo" class="cuadrado" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="verde" class="cuadrado" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="marron" class="cuadrado" onmouseover="cambio(this)"></div>
  <div id="CajaCambiante"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Referencia:** [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Sé que llego un poco tarde, pero aquí un consejo: te podrías ahorrar `window.getComputedStyle(...)` con solo poner `getComputedStyle(...)`, pues cada elemento que contenga `window` tiene su alcance por si solo sin depender de `window` (lo puedes comprobar con `window.getComputedStyle === getComputedStyle // true`)